# Converting two methods to pass the "T" for generic being used

Tags: c#, generics

I was working on a program where I had the following two methods. Obviously when you look at them they are very repetitive so I was hoping to refactor them to one method called IEnumerable`<dynamic>`GetRecords(csv,?,?). Where I am having trouble is understand when I create the method what do I need to do to pass paramaters that allow me to substitute what T will be for the RegisterMapClass and then the T for the GetRecords.

```
       private static IEnumerable<LeadRecord> GetLeadRecords()
    {
        using (TextReader textLeadReader = File.OpenText("Leads.csv"))
        {
            var csvLeads = new CsvReader(textLeadReader);
            csvLeads.Configuration.RegisterClassMap<LeadRecordMap>();
            return  csvLeads.GetRecords<LeadRecord>().ToList();
        }
    }

    private static IEnumerable<AccountRecord> GetAccountRecords()
    {
        using (TextReader txtAccountsReader = File.OpenText("Accounts.csv"))
        {
            var csvAccounts = new CsvReader(txtAccountsReader);
            csvAccounts.Configuration.RegisterClassMap<AccountRecordMap>();
            return csvAccounts.GetRecords<AccountRecord>().ToList();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can refactor your two methods for this

```
private static IEnumerable<T> GetRecords<T, TMap>(string filename)
{
    using (TextReader reader = File.OpenText(filename))
    {
        using(var csvReader = new CsvReader(reader)) 
        {
            csvReader.Configuration.RegisterClassMap<TMap>();
            return csvReader.GetRecords<T>().ToList();
        }
    }
}
```

You can then invoke the method this way :

```
var records = GetRecords<LeadRecord, LeadRecordMap>("file.csv");
```

Comment: Based on some of the other comments from the answer above this will not perfectly compile but it was enough to get past where I was stuck which was being able to pass in the T types. If someone else was working with the csvhelper nuget package you will also need to change the first line to : private static IEnumerable<T> GetRecords<T, TMap>(string filename) where TMap : CsvClassMap

Answer (score 3):

Something like this?

```
private static IEnumerable<T> GetAccountRecords<T,T2>(string filename) 
{
    using (TextReader txtAccountsReader = File.OpenText(filename))
    {
        var csvAccounts = new CsvReader(txtAccountsReader);
        csvAccounts.Configuration.RegisterClassMap<T2>();
        return csvAccounts.GetRecords<T>();
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd name the type arguments better. (And who cares about the compiler errors in this answer? Just fix them yourself.)

Comment: @usr: I care. Answers that don't compile are "good" answers? I get the point but that won't do much but erode SO's quality.

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils I answer with (accidentally) non-compiling code all the time. I answer conceptionally hard questions and I give the key insight to the solution. I don't care about the OP having to fix trivial errors. Going the last mile is his job.

Comment: @usr But if you're answering a (fairly) simple question with a (fairly) simple piece of code, that code should at least 1) compile and 2) work.

Comment: @Corey why exactly should it? This answer provides the key insight. Job done successfully. OP can move on.

Comment: @usr Because half an answer is not an answer.  A quality answer to a simple question should include some explanation of _why_, not just _what_.  In a class environment where you _should_ be leading someone through a thinking process, hints and clues are viable techniques.  But this is not that environment.

Comment: @usr And no, I don't think SO should be a place people come to get people to write code for them.  The OP obviously needs some more explanation of how generics function, not just some compilable code to drop into their program that they don't understand.

Answer (score 1):

Just to expand the accepted answer, following should compile:

```
    private static IEnumerable<T> GetRecords<T, TMap>(string filename)
        where T : class
        where TMap : ClassMap<T>
    {
        using (TextReader reader = File.OpenText(filename))
        {
            using (var csvReader = new CsvReader(reader))
            {
                csvReader.Configuration.RegisterClassMap<TMap>();
                return csvReader.GetRecords<T>();
            }
        }
    }
```